# Limiting store hours in Spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I've integrated Spree with my current website (which is built with Ruby on Rails).

It's a fast-food ordering service, and I want orders to be placed ONLY in the opening hours (12:00 - 22:00).

I've never done this before, can someone guide me a bit? Thanks!

Comment: what server-side language are you using? (this can be done w JavaScript, PHP, Ruby, or any other language; however, they all vary a little bit)

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't specify this, I'm using Ruby on Rails. Thanks

Comment: you might want to add some code to your question (from one of your views and/or controllers) this will help to provide a more concrete answer.

Comment: Hi - here at Stack Overflow we prefer for you to have a go at this yourself, then come to use to help you get past the tricky bits. We want to see that you've put some effort into it, because we don't want to write your code for you. Have a go at all the bits you know how to do. write pseudo code for the bits where you know roughly what has to be done... and come back and show us what you've got.

Comment: @Gibson take a look at https://spreecommerce.com/extensions/359-spree-store-hours whether it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strftime` to get the current time. Then use a simple `if/else` statement (if between 12:00 and 22:00 we'll accept orders/else we won't)

```
puts Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %z") # "09:33:00 -0400"

puts Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %Z %z") # "09:33:00 EDT -0400"
```

Comment: I have a column called :open_time and :close_time , how can I say:
If Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %z") is between :open_time and :close_time ?

Comment: `if Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %z") > :open_time && Time.now.strftime("%I:%M:%S %z") < :close_time`

Answer (score 0):

I've never used spree so I'm not exactly sure where this would go but you can check if a time is between two other times w/ [between?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/between%3F)

```
open = Time.now.beginning_of_day + 12.hours
close = Time.now.end_of_day - 2.hours

Time.now.between? open, close
```